# CSS selector for general textboxes

Tags: html, css, input, css-selectors

Is there a way to select every kind of textbox with a CSS selector to give them all the same width, for instance? By textbox, I simply mean something that the user can type into.

My problem is that there are so many of them. It used to be reasonably straightforward; you only had 2 types of textbox with HTML4. These two types were `text` and `password`, so the CSS could be

```
input:not([type]), input[type='text'], input[type='password'] {...}
```

This would cover all of the types. However, with the invention of HTML5, you get many more types, such as `number`, `email`, `url`, `search` and `tel`, that all look and behave the same (except for what you're supposed to type into them), and I'd like to address them all in the same way through CSS.

Is it absolutely necessary to write all of this?

```
input:not([type]),
input[type='text'],
input[type='password'],
input[type='number'],
input[type='email'],
input[type='url'],
input[type='search'],
input[type='tel'] {...}
```

Is there possibly a much more code efficient way of writing this?

Comment: Why not simply `input` then designate specific input types you want to alter from the default CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Do saner solutions exist?***

How about a good old fashion class?

`<input class='text' type='text'>`

or overriding the types that are not text

```
input {
    background: red;
}

input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox], input[type=submit] {
    background: yellow;
}
```

---

Additionally:
In my books there is nothing really wrong with your solution.

You just need to add the new [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) input types:

- color
- date
- datetime
- datetime-local
- email
- month
- number
- range
- search
- tel
- time
- url
- week

Comment: The class is a good plan. I'll accept this one if no other, astonishingly brilliant, solutions come along. The problem with your other solution "override the three types..." is that there are much more than three non-text types of control. And other types of control may be defined in the future, which all become red in this scenario.

Comment: You could also invert this logic and use :not again: `input:not([type=radio], [type=checkbox], [type=submit], [type=file])`

Answer (score 1):

### A Few Thoughts On Reducing Selectors

[Using information from mozilla...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input)

Assuming you set a `placeholder` attribute on the relevant inputs, then you can capture `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url` or `email` with `input[placeholder]`.

If instead you consistently set `size` or `maxlength` for only those text inputs they are valid for, then you can capture `password` along with those listed above in a similarly succinct selector `input[size]` or `input[maxlength]`.

All three dates can be caught by `input[type^=date]`.

**Lowest Denominator for Type Matching Selectors**

This uses `size` to reduce the total to nine (at present), but `maxlength` might be preferred, or `placeholder` in which case the additional `input[type=password]` would need added to make ten:

```
input:not([type]), /* all non-declared types */
input[size], /* text, search, tel, url email, or password */
input[type^=date], /* date, datetime, datetime-local */
input[type=color],
input[type=week],
input[type=month],
input[type=time],
input[type=number],
input[type=range] {
   /* styles */
}
```

If you are just concerned with the eight types noted in your question, then it reduces further (assuming they are being given `size` or optionally `maxlength` to replace `size` below) to:

```
input:not([type]), /* all non-declared types */
input[size], /* text, search, tel, url email, or password */
input[type=number] {
   /* styles */
}
```

Comment: Good tips, all. Thanks. I think I'll stick with Blowsie's answer though.

Comment: You are welcome. I would go with a class (as Blowsie first points out) if it were me (unless, of course, I am creating a "reset" type style sheet for text inputs).

Answer (score 1):

The [`:read-write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-write) pseudo-class applies to any element with editable text, so you can achieve most of what you want by combining that with an attribute selector for `readonly`. Note that `disabled` textboxes won't be matched.

```
:read-write {
   /* Your styles here */
}
:-moz-read-write {
   /* Your styles here */
}
[readonly] {
   /* Your styles here */
}
```

You have to use separate blocks rather than comma-separated selectors because browsers that don't understand the pseudo-class will ignore the entire rule.